# Using XPath to select button inside HTML with content of tag instead of numbered list

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using python + selenium to automate common behavior through a website. I have now arrived at a point where there is a div `<div class="teetime-grid" data-baan="1">` with a number of `<div class="btn btn-success teetime has-bookings>` inside `<a href>` tags. Please find a snippet of the HTML page below to clarify.

```
<div class="teetime-grid" data-baan="1">
    <a href="#">

        <div class="btn btn-success teetime has-bookings " data-time="1645165200"
             title="Er zijn nog 3 beschikbare plaatsen op deze starttijd">
            <span class="time">07:20</span>
            <div class="icons">
                <span class="icon bezet geslacht-m">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="icon vrij">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="icon vrij">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="icon vrij">&nbsp;</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">

        <div class="btn btn-success teetime has-bookings " data-time="1645165800"
             title="Er zijn nog 1 beschikbare plaatsen op deze starttijd">
            <span class="time">07:30</span>
            <div class="icons">
                <span class="icon bezet geslacht-m">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="icon bezet geslacht-m">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="icon bezet geslacht-m">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="icon vrij">&nbsp;</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to access specific `<div class="btn btn-success teetime has-bookings>` inside the grid. In Selenium, I know I can do this by using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[2]/div")
```

To select the second  tag in my above example, which in this case has a corresponding time of 07:30 associated with it (it's defined in the `<span class="time">07:30</span>`).

Is there also a way to access these elements by the contents of the `<span class="time">` instead of specifying the number in the list of `<a href>` tags? Because now I still have to know which `a[?]` number corresponds to a certain time. If I have to look this up manually every time time there is no point in automating this browser action to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the specific `<div class="btn btn-success teetime has-bookings>` corresponding to the different time you can the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Selecting *07:20*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[./span[text()='07:20']]")
  ```
- Selecting *07:30*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[./span[text()='07:30']]")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This will find the `div`, which contains a specific span child 1 level down.

```
//span[@class='time'][text()='07:30']/..
```

And if you'll add one more `/..`, you'll find the `a` (the div parent).